# Calculated column in wrong position when using `SELECT *`

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, oledb, ado

Consider this query that uses `SELECT *` and 'appends' a calculated column:

```
SELECT *, 
       IIF(TRUE, 1, 0) AS calculated_col
  FROM Orders;
```

I would expect `calculated_col` to be the rightmost column in the resultset. However, it is in fact the leftmost column. It is the rightmost when executing the equivalent query in SQL Server, for example.

Now, because this is Access (ACE, Jet, whatever), the SQL Standards don't apply and the Access Help will not specify the expected result because it is not detailed enough (to put it politely). So my questions are:

Does Access always behaved this way or is it a 'feature' of my environment (ADO, OLE DB provider, etc)?

Has Access always behaved this way in the given environment? (i.e. Why haven't I noticed this before?)

P.S. I know of course that `SELECT *` is widely derided and that if the order of columns is important to me then I should write them all out explicitly. However, I was genuinely suprised at the actual behaviour encountered and am interested in any answers to my questions.

Here's some VBA to reproduce the behaviour: just copy+paste into any VBA module, no references need to be set and Access need not be installed e.g. use Excel's VBA editor:

```
Sub ColumnOrderWrong()

  On Error Resume Next
  Kill Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"
  On Error GoTo 0

  Dim cat
  Set cat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
  With cat
    .Create _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & _
        Environ$("temp") & "\DropMe.mdb"
    With .ActiveConnection

      Dim Sql As String
      Sql = _
      "CREATE TABLE Orders" & vbCr & _
      "(" & vbCr & " ID INTEGER, " & vbCr & _
      " customer_id" & _
      " INTEGER" & vbCr & _
      ");"
      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
      "INSERT INTO Orders (ID, customer_id) VALUES" & _
      " (1, 2);"
      .Execute Sql

      Sql = _
      "SELECT *, " & vbCr & _
      "       IIF(TRUE, 55, -99) AS calculated_col" & vbCr & _
      "  FROM Orders;"
      Dim rs
      Set rs = .Execute(Sql)

      MsgBox _
      "Fields(0).Name = " & rs.Fields(0).Name & vbCr & _
      "Fields(1).Name = " & rs.Fields(1).Name & vbCr & _
      "Fields(2).Name = " & rs.Fields(2).Name

    End With
    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you ever use * without the table name? If you write bad SQL, you get unreliable results, so don't write bad (i.e., ambiguous) SQL.

Comment: In Standard SQL, the results are predictable and unambiguous. In Access the results aren't even defined, therefore Access IMO is the "bad SQL" here. Why should adding the table name make a difference to the result if there is but one table in the `FROM` clause?

Comment: Is the column order actually defined in the SQL Standards? Or is it just that everybody but Jet/ACE just conventionally uses the order of the SELECT to display the fields? I can certainly see how that's logical, but unless the SQL standard defines how it should be presented, then I don't think you have a leg to stand on here.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: I believe it is covered in the SQL-92 spec by sections 7.9 (syntax rules 3 and 4) and 7.4 (general rules case 1b) but admit I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: Try [this](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt).

Comment: I'm not seeing how that implies anything about column order when mixing `*` and calculated columns in the SELECT. In short, my surmise aspears to be correct, that there is no spec here for any database engine to follow, and so you really shouldn't be counting on any particular column ordering. I would agree that your preferred colum order seems to be commonsensical, I can also intuit a definition under which Jet/ACE interprets it the way it does (it's encoded in the query properties sheet of the Access query designer -- "Show all fields" adds `*` to the SELECT).

Comment: I've had it confirmed from a reliable source that Fenton was indeed correct. In fact, the SQL standard requires that if `*` (as distinct from `COUNT(*)`) is used in the `SELECT` clause (i.e. not dot-qualified)  then no other columns may appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the investigations you've already done, it looks like you're stuffed.

You may have to reference the record set's column's by name rather than position.

Comment: The usage I rather had in mind was using the query construct in another SQL construct for which column ordering matters e.g. `UNION` of logical tables. The recordset is merely the vehicle I'm using to view the results.

Answer (score 2):

Change your select statement to:

```
  Sql = _
       "SELECT Orders.*, " & vbCr & _
       "       IIF(TRUE, 55, -99) AS calculated_col" & vbCr & _
       "  FROM Orders;"
```

By declaring the table name, I think it prevents having to determine what is the default table.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL code in the question is proscribed by the SQL standard: when `*` is used without dot-qualification (and disregarding the special case `COUNT(*)`) then no other columns may appear.

This gives a clue to the solution: dot-qualify the `*` !!

e.g. this works as expected, with `calculated_column` appearing as the rightmost column in the result:

```
SELECT Orders.*, 
       IIF(TRUE, 1, 0) AS calculated_col
  FROM Orders;
```