# MS Access select statement, select *, ' ' from sometable shows the following result

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

In MS Access the query `SELECT *, ' ' from sometable` shows the following result:

```
      EXPR001 field1 field2 
      ------- ------ --------
      some   some
      value  value
```

(result 1)

While in SQL Server or other MSDB the above query result is:

```
      field1 field2 EXPR001
      ------ ------- -------
      some   some
      value  value
```

(result 2)

Is there some way some configuration some miracle some something (with condition) without changing the SQL query to run the query in MS Access such that it gives the result 2 above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculated column in wrong position when using `SELECT *`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623207/calculated-column-in-wrong-position-when-using-select)

Answer (score 1):

Although this question **is** a duplicate of the one *onedaywhen* mentioned, it might not be very clear what the solution is.

So, you need to use TableName.* to get the right order. Like the following:

```
Select SomeTable.*, "" As EXPR001 From SomeTable
```

Or, list all columns individually:

```
Select SomeTable.Field1, SomeTable.Field2, "" As EXPR001 From SomeTable
```

Comment: Furthermore with the expression: "SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.field1 = table2 .field1  WHERE ..."
I was getting a blank textbox connected with table1.field1
But Igor's solution corrects this problem also. 
new expression:
 "SELECT table1.* FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.field1 = table2 .field1  WHERE ..."

Answer (score 0):

In Access, you can move the columns of a query, in *Datasheet view*, without affecting the order of the columns in *Design view*. Both are saved. You can deduct from that, that an Access also stores you display preferences (including hidden columns, column widths etc) in the query.